# Flutter TextField text with background covers cursor

Tags: flutter, textfield

The text in my TextField has a background. But the background covers the cursor. Is there a solution for this issue? This might be a bug - the cursor shouldn't fall behind the background of the text. Here is an example of the TextField below:

```
TextField(
                  autofocus: true,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                  maxLines: null,
                  cursorColor: Colors.white,
                  cursorWidth: 3.0,
                  textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      background: Paint()
                        ..strokeWidth = 30.0
                        ..color = Colors.white
                        ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
                        ..strokeJoin = StrokeJoin.round),
                );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the way to have a background color in a `TextField` would be with a decoration.
Something along the lines of:

```
TextField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
      fillColor: Colors.red,
      filled: true,
      border: OutlineInputBorder()),
  autofocus: true,
  keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
  maxLines: null,
  cursorColor: Colors.blue,
  cursorWidth: 3.0,
  textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
  style: TextStyle(
    color: Colors.black,
  ),
),
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  But this TextField doesn't achieve the same effect as the TextField I posted above.  Your TextField creates a TextField window completely filled with color, regardless of whether the entered text fills the TextField.  On the other hand, in my TextField, the color is coupled to the text.  For instance, if there is no text, there is no color behind it. Or if there are just a few characters, the background is only behind those few characters.

Comment: Should I report this as a bug?

Comment: @CyrusG yes definetely report this as a bug